# Evenly dividing up table items in columns

Tags: table-field

I'm building out my first Craft site and learning a whole lot so far. Coming from ExpressionEngine, this really seems like what EE should have been.

Anyway, I'm trying to find a way divide up content from a table field into three even columns. For example, if I have content in 9 rows in a table, I would like to have 3 items per column. Is this possible with Twig?  Here is the HTML.  Thank you!

```
<div class="medium-3 medium-offset-2 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="medium-3 medium-offset-2 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="medium-3 medium-offset-2 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

It's actually quite simple! What you're looking for is [Twig's `batch` filter...](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) Ironically, the example given on that page is nearly identical to what you are requesting.

I've adapted the example to more closely match what you're looking for:

```
{% set myData = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] %}

{% for column in myData|batch(3, 'No item') %}
    <div class="medium-3 medium-offset-2 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
        <ul>
            {% for item in column %}
                <li>{{ item }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Lindsey, I did see that, however this will create multiple columns with ONLY three list items in that column. What I actually need is ONLY three columns at the most that can divide up the amount of list items

Comment: With a little addition to the solution of Lindsey you can achieve this. Instead of using a fixed value "3" for the batch you could calculate the size of each list before.

    {% set loopLength = myData|length % 3 %}

    {% for column in myData|batch(loopLength, 'No item') %}

Comment: @PascalMollet This worked like a charm for me! But instead i divided the array by the number of columns I wanted, instead of using %